# Turning raw/baking cocoa powder into instant cocoa (Kaba/Nesquik)

Tags: chocolate, additives

The question on [Dissolving cocoa powder in milk](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/dissolving-cocoa-powder-in-milk) describes the two common workarounds for making chocolate milk with raw cocoa powder. While obviously it works easiest with hot milk, making cocoa slime/mud is a functioning alternative. It's however not very practical, which is why I want to renew this topic. However I'm not settling for anything but achieving something comparable to **instant cocoa**. So would rather like this question to border on food chemistry or industrial espionage. (Most likely the solution is some food additive though..)

So what's the magic behind Kaba or Nesquik? How do they turn cocoa dust into instant chocolate milk powder?

I've already figured out that ordinary baking cocoa is the *weakly de-oiled* one. Obviously the oil stipend contributes to the difficulty of mixing it with cold fluids. - So I went out and bought some **strongly de-oiled cocoa**, which subjectively mixes better already. (But that might be just [post-purchase rationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-purchase_rationalization).) Adding glucose powder also helps both flavour and mixing abilities.

Yet that doesn't solve the issue satisfactory and still requires making a slurry. So there is probably really some food additive necessary. I've also (can't find link) read somewhere about steam (hot water) playing a role in turning cocoa powder into instant granules. But also obviously, I'm looking for something you can do in an ordinary kitchen, and which doesn't involve inventing complex machinery. So, do you have any tips, expert knowledge, links?

Answer (score 7):

The magic emulsifier is probably soy lecithin.

According to [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Soy_lecithin#Use_with_food.2C_and_health_effects):

> It is used commercially in foods requiring a natural emulsifier or lubricant. In the food industry it has multiple uses: In confectionery it reduces viscosity, replaces more expensive ingredients, controls sugar crystallization and the flow properties of chocolate, helps in the homogeneous mixing of ingredients, improves shelf life for some products, and can be used as a coating.

The magic soluble is probably a [hydrochloride](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hydrochloride):

> Converting insoluble amines into hydrochlorides is a common way to make them water- and acid-soluble