# How can I prevent the cocoa in my hot chocolate from solidifying over time?

Tags: milk, cocoa

I make my own hot chocolate by making a slurry of cocoa powder and warm milk being sure that the chocolate is nicely melted and smooth.  Then I add the rest of the milk and heat it the rest of the way.  I just use the microwave for single-servings.  No chocolate clumps -- everything's GREAT.

However, by the time I start to get to the bottom of my cup, the chocolate has started to "fall out" of the milk clumping on the bottom.  I can re-heat and re-incorporate it, but I'd rather avoid the problem altogether.  Any ideas?

**Related questions** -- These address the initial creation of a smooth mixture and not the longevity.

[Dissolving cocoa powder in milk](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/dissolving-cocoa-powder-in-milk?rq=1)

[How can I make milk cocoa powder so it does not stick to the top and bottom?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16467/how-can-i-make-milk-cocoa-powder-so-it-does-not-stick-to-the-top-and-bottom)

Comment: A [mug warmer](http://www.amazon.com/Mr-Coffee-MWBLK-Mug-Warmer/dp/B000CO89T8)? I'm not actually sure this would do what you want, but it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply heat.

It's not quite what you were looking for, but it's probably the only solution that won't involve adding chemicals.

Basically, a set amount of milk can hold a specific amount of chocolate in suspension. The hotter it is (below boiling), the more it can hold. That's why as the milk cools, the chocolate it can no longer hold falls to the bottom of the cup.

The three options are:

1. Keep it warm, by using a mug warmer (like Catija suggested). If it doesn't cool, it won't lose the ability to hold the chocolate.
2. Start with less chocolate, that way, it won't be too much for the milk when it's cooling. Obviously, this will affect the flavour.
3. Add chemical additives, like emulsifiers, which will allow the milk to hold more chocolate.

As I said at the beginning, I think the best option is the first one. Apply heat.

Comment: Thanks -- good and informative.  It sounds like I'll just have more excuses to take breaks :)