# Making my cocoa mix into instant cocoa mix

Tags: chocolate, milk

Yes, I have read the answers to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/dissolving-cocoa-powder-in-milk/43055#43055), but none of them are what I am after. I even posted an answer there, but it is an expensive, if delicious one. The key word I am after is **instant** cocoa mix. Please don't suggest a blender.

I came up with a cocoa recipe I quite like (1 Tbs sugar, 4 tsp unpacked cocoa powder, 2-3 cups of milk - yes, I generally prefer more cocoa powder than sugar). However, I would like to make it an instant mix, rather than having to mix a small amount with hot water, mix that first, then add milk (or use a blender I don't want to wash).

Obviously this is achievable as cocoa mixes off the store shelf don't require this extra step. What are my options for making my cocoa mix truly "instant" (I don't care if it becomes syrup instead of a mix, just as long as there is no powdered milk in there - ugh, who in the world decided there could be *gourmet* cocoa with powdered milk, there is no such thing as *gourmet* powdered milk)

Comment: Hmmm, [Alton Brown's mix](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/hot-cocoa-recipe.html) doesn't require an extra step.

Comment: "Obviously this is achievable": nothing obvious about it. Store bought mixes contain more sugar than cocoa. The sugar separates the cocoa particles, and when it dissolves, the cocoa doesn't clump. There may be a different method which might work for your mix, but between your different ratio and the impossibility to do industrial processing at home, there is no guarantee that what you want is achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the ingredients for Nesquick for example:

- SUGAR
- COCOA PROCESSED WITH ALKALI
- SOY LECITHIN
- CARRAGEENAN
- SALT
- ARTIFICIAL FLAVORS
- SPICE
- VITAMINS AND MINERALS: CALCIUM CARBONATE, ASCORBIC ACID (VITAMIN C), ZINC OXIDE, PYRIDOXINE HYDROCHLORIDE (VITAMIN B6), COPPER GLUCONATE, MANGANESE SULFATE, BIOTIN.

The key elements are soy lecithin, which is an emulsifier, and carrageenan, which is a thickener especially effective in dairy products.  The lecithin will help the cocoa to become suspended in the liquid phase, and the carrageenan will help the particles not stick to each other.

What does not appear on the label is how some of these ingredients are processed.  It is likely that the cocoa is modified by being pre-gelatinized, so that  it will have reduced clumping properties, and then reground quite fine to enhance how well it dissolves.  This is not something that you can achieve at home.

---

As you mention, you can probably create a syrup from your ingredients, but it may settle over time and have to be shaken.