# How do I dissolve chunky powder completely in milk?

Tags: milk

I am talking especially about [Cadbury Bournvita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bournvita).

That powder has tiny and somewhat hard chunks in it which don't get dissolved easily. How do dissolve it completely in milk?

Comment: how different is this from other chocolate powders like Ovaltine?  I seem to remember that one in particular being more chunky than Nestle Quik.  If it's not more coarse than sand (nothing larger than 2mm), you might take a look at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8274/67

Comment: I have hershey's cocoa powder. It is all smooth and not at all difficult to mix. Mine is a "chunky" powder, chunks are not smooth, they are small and don't get broken easily.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Q&A linked by @Joe has most of the tricks in it. Hot, paste, make syrup, blender, etc. Mixing stuff into cold milk (unless specially prepped for that) is not a good scene. Surprising they haven't done better at that given the marketing, but corporate competence is a rare thing - they may be too big to get someone that knows how to make a powder dissolve in cold milk working where they need to work - Nestle solved that one (at least) 50 years ago. Too many vice presidents, and not enough food science engineers? Puzzling.

If you have "small hard chunks" either pre-grind dry in a mortar and pestle, or grind the paste step suggested in the other answer in a mortar and pestle with a little liquid.

Or contact Cadbury all wide eyed and innocent and ask why you get little hard chunks when you mix their product (I assume, as instructed on the package) 8-)

Comment: Everything about the product site seems to imply that it's designed for cold consumption, though... I though the same thing, that mixing into hot was necessary because it had some actual chocolate chunks that needed melting but I removed the comment because it looks like it's designed for cold.

Comment: The reason not all producers, produce easy to mix powders is an effort to be 100% "natural". Products like nestle use stuff sugar or maltodextrin to ease the mixing process.

Answer (score 3):

As [Ecnerwal](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/55843/26972) answer implies, there are various ways, but from my experience with baking-grade cocoa: go with pasting. Add a LITTLE milk at first, stir, repeat until you have a paste, continue adding milk slowly and stirring until you have a liquid. Then add all the milk and/or other liquids you want.
I do this for making even hot chocolate drinks, because it dissolves almost-undissolvable baking-cocoa just fine :).

Comment: Cocoa powder is actually insoluble, and the last I read about it, it might still be an open research question which nobody has a complete solution to yet. Here's a pretty old but relevant article - https://www.newfoodmagazine.com/article/1290/will-cocoa-ever-dissolve-in-water/. The physical and chemical makeup of cocoa powder is just different from most other soluble beverage powders.

Answer (score 1):

An undersized wire loop wisk is indispensable for mixing dry products that clump into liquids smoothly, from powdered milk to dry gravy mixes to protein powders.